# using rsync do compress whole directory during copy

Tags: ssh, directory, rsync, compression, copy

Files, Folders, Sub folders from system1 are successfully copying to system2 using below command

> rsync -avzP -u -v -e ssh /opt/lampp/htdocs/files/*
>    demo@192.168.157.130:~/files_backup

I need to compress the whole folder "files" during copying. It means I need only compressed file

Any help will be highly appreciable

Regards

Comment: They get compressed while they transfer.

Answer (score 2):

`rsync` is using compression during the transfert, if you are not doing differential backups, you can use `tar` to compress before and `scp` to transfert the compressed files directory.

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/files/
tar czvf ../files.backup.tar.gz .
cd ..
scp /opt/lampp/htdocs/files.backup.tar.gz demo@192.168.157.130:~/files_backup
```